# JavaScript trim line breaks with regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, line-breaks, trim

I am using Google Translate to translate the contents of a textarea and fill another textarea with the API response.
In my source textarea I am replacing the `/n` newlines with `<br />` line breaks to send the query like this:

```
var query   = $('#textarea-src').val();
var query   = encodeURIComponent(query);
var query   = query.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />'); // replace new lines with line breaks
```

Then I make the call to Google:

```
$.ajax({
    url: apiUrl,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) { 
        var response = data.data.translations[0].translatedText;
        var response = response.replace(/ <br \/> ?/g, '\n'); // replace line breaks with new lines
        $('#textarea-trg').val(response);
    }
});
```

The problem is that Google's responses have whitespace around the line breaks.
When I query `"hello<br />world"` the response in French is `"bonjour \u003cbr /\u003e monde"`

With my `replace(/ <br \/> ?/g, '\n')` regex I can correct for that but when I query two line breaks after each other `"hello<br /><br />world"` the response is `"bonjour \u003cbr /\u003e\u003cbr /\u003e monde"`

How can I correct for this?

Comment: It begs the question: why are you replacing the linebreaks with `<br/>`s?

Comment: @cheeken. I'm not sure, but for valid XHTML all tags must be closed (or self-closed)

Comment: @Andrew To clarify, by 'linebreak' I meant the `\n`s.  I am wondering with FFish wants to replace the `\n`s with `<br/>`s at all.  If the problem is the GET request and invalid characters, that can be resolved with encoding.

Comment: @cheeken - That's a good point. The `$.ajax` is missing the `data` parameter, so it may be wrongly encoded in the URL.

Comment: I'd venture there's no reason to do the replacement before sending the data to Google. You can do that after and avoid the mess.

Comment: @cheeken it seems Google Translate does not respond the new lines. Query URI: https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=MY-KEY&q=hello%0A%0Aworld&source=en&target=fr Response: "translatedText": "Bonjour tout le monde"

Comment: @Kobi I forgot to mention I encoded using `encodeURIComponent()` I have updated my original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the spaces optional on both sides:

```
var response = response.replace(/ ?<br \/> ?/g, '\n');
```

Another option is using `/ *<br \/> */g` or `/\s*<br \/>\s*/g`.

For clarity, lets use underscores instead of spaces:
If your text is `"a_<br />_<br />_b"`, `/_<br \/>_?/g` fails because the first match consumes the second space (resulting in `"a\n<br />_b"`), and the second `<br />` cannot be matched without a leading space.

Comment: @FFish - no problem. I would take note of cheeken's comment though - there is probably a much better solution to your problem.

Comment: before replacing the query I used `encodeURIComponent(query)`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var query   = $('#textarea-src').val();
var query   = query.replace(/\n|\r/g, '<br\/>'); // replace new lines with line breaks
```

Or, if posible, firstly send request for translating into Google, then replace newlines|linefeeds with `BR`

Comment: That's not really the problem the OP is having. Besides, `"a\n\r\b"` (2 lines total), which is an explorer-style new line, will be converted to `"a<br/><br/>b"`, and then to `"a\n\n\b"` (3 lines). On other browsers it should work.